# Getting only one row of a mysql table displayed using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I Currently have this code that displays all entries rows from a mysql table and displays them on a web page;

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "appuser1";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "acmefg_app";

$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT jobnumber FROM appdata WHERE id = '5608' LIMIT 1"));

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, jobnumber, assetnumber FROM appdata";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"].  "<br>";
         echo "<br> Job number: ". $row["jobnumber"]. "<br>";
         echo "<br> Asset number: " . $row["assetnumber"] . "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

How can I change this so it only displays one result? Lets say in this case I wanted to display the row with an id of 5611? Many Thanks

Comment: This code is confusing me, both mysql functions and OO mysqli?

Comment: To show only the first record you can add a LIMIT 1 to mysql query. To show only one id you need to add a variable to the query and populate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show only one row then no need to use `while()` loop. Remove loop

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"].  "<br>";
    echo "<br> Job number: ". $row["jobnumber"]. "<br>";
    echo "<br> Asset number: " . $row["assetnumber"] . "<br>";
}
```

Or can set [**LIMIT**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) 1 in your query string.

```
SELECT id, jobnumber, assetnumber FROM appdata LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You'd wanna include here that the query should have a WHERE clause and should be limitted by 1, ensuring that actually one result is returned. then the if should also be changed to if($result->num_rows == 0).

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. But One more thing I needed, I want to put a plain black border around the results, similar to what you can do with CSS p.one {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}

Comment: So insert inside a div & can use `style="border: 5px solid #aaa;"`.

Comment: Hello,
I hate to seem really stupid, but when I try this using the <div "style="border: 5px solid #aaa;">
</div> It comes up with a syntax error Unexpected "<"

Comment: It should be `<div style="border: 5px solid #aaa;"> </div>`